# I need help formating an output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making an 'interface' for a war game with my freinds so we dont need 100's of cards they can all be in a program. in also adding a dice roller to it i found an article that worked but was a bit outdatted really inefficent and didnt work with my program for a couple of reasons so i decided to rewrite it my self and it worked but the only thing i strugled with was the format of the output at the minite mine looks like this

```
1
3
2
4
5
4
```

and the article i founds looked like this (after some slight modification)

```
[1,3,2,4,5,4]
```

and im not sure how to get it like this.

```
import random

def dice_roller():
    num = input('Enter a number from [1-20] or "home" to exit')
    if num in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']:
        for i in range(int(num)):
            print(random.randint(1,6))
```

this is the code its not done yet any ideas Thanks.

Comment: Show your code.  take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: there you go @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to get your output in a list

```
import random

 
def dice_roller():
    num = input('Enter a number from [1-20] or "home" to exit')
    if num in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']:
        res_list = [random.randint(1,6) for i in range(int(num))]
    print(res_list)
    
print(dice_roller())
```

Comment: What was the output of running this code? What happens if the input value is "home"? What happens if the input value is, for example, "21"

Comment: @CtrlZ I think it's VERY CLEAR that OP simply posted a reproducible example for the problem he was facing. Please read his question again. He had NO PROBLEMS with what you're saying. His problem was clearly specified. Please you're a 22k rep, act like one.

Comment: This code will presumably be in a while loop and OP perhaps knows how to use the break statement if a user types "home". His question was simply how to get his output in a list which I fixed in my code. If you have a better answer, post it and if he likes yours, he can accept. I really don't care

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify the input validation by creating a global set of allowable values.

You also need to test for an input value of "home" as well as ensuring that the input value is within the stated range.

Try this:

```
from random import randint

LO = 1
HI = 20
RANGE = set(str(r) for r in range(LO, HI + 1))

def dice_roller():
    while (num := input(f'Enter a number from [{LO}-{HI}] or "home" to exit: ')) != "home":
        if num in RANGE:
            return [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(int(num))]
        print(f'\a"{num}" is not a valid response')
    # implicit return of None when user input is "home"

print(dice_roller())
```